# sum object value in javascript by name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sum, nested-lists

I have a data that type is object and I want to sum the value1 + value 2 as totalValue per each name by using for

```js
//this is my object  
{
111:{name:'a', value1: 2 , value2: 2},
222:{name:'b', value1: 3 , value2: 3},
333:{name:'c', value1: 4 , value2: 4},
 }
 
 // this is the result that I expected
 {
 {name:'a' , totalValue:4},
 {name:'b' , totalValue:6},
 {name:'c' , totalValue:8},
 }
```

Comment: The expected result is *not* a valid object.

Answer (score 1):

1. Transform the object into an array of key value pairs using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
2. Then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the entries and calculate the `totalValue` property.
3. Finally transform the array back to an object using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const obj = {
  111: { name: "a", value1: 2, value2: 2 },
  222: { name: "b", value1: 3, value2: 3 },
  333: { name: "c", value1: 4, value2: 4 },
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, { name: v.name, totalValue: v.value1 + v.value2 }])
);

console.log(result);
```

If there are multiple value properties that you wish to add, then refer to the solution below:

```js
const obj = {
  111: { name: "a", value1: 2, value2: 2 },
  222: { name: "b", value1: 3, value2: 3 },
  333: { name: "c", value1: 4, value2: 4 },
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [
    k,
    {
      name: v.name,
      totalValue: Object.keys(v)
        .filter((k) => k.includes("value"))
        .reduce((s, k) => s + v[k], 0),
    },
  ])
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const obj = {
  111: {
    name: 'a',
    value1: 2,
    value2: 2,
    value3: 4
  },
  222: {
    name: 'b',
    value1: 3,
    value2: 3
  },
  333: {
    name: 'c',
    value1: 4,
    value2: 4
  },
};
const result = [];
for (const key in obj) {
  const item = obj[key];
  let total = 0;
  const final = {};
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (key.startsWith('value')) {
      total += item[key];
    } else {
      final[key] = item[key];
    }
  })
  final.totalValue = total;
  result.push(final);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is not a valid object.

Here is some possible codes.

```js
const obj = {
  111:{name:'a', value1: 2 , value2: 2},
  222:{name:'b', value1: 3 , value2: 3},
  333:{name:'c', value1: 4 , value2: 4},
};
const arrResult = Object.values(obj)
  .map(({ name, value1, value2 }) => ({ name, totalValue: value1 + value2 }));
const objResult = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(([key, { name, value1, value2 }]) => ({ key, value: { name, totalValue: value1 + value2 } }))
  .reduce((acc, cur) => { acc[cur.key] = cur.value; return acc; }, {});
```